# let φ: G-H be an isomorphism of groups show that Z(G)≌Z(H)

Tags: group-theory

let φ: G-H be an isomorphism of groups and show that Z(G)≌Z(H).
I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. 
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts 
and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, 
and help them give their answers at the right level. This site uses 
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Restrict the isomorphism to the center of G.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the center of G. What does the isomorphism do to your elements in the center? Can you show that the image is the center of H?

Comment: Can you write down some proof for me?